# Как я могу использовать videojs плагин вместе с RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

[оригинал](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34163777/how-can-i-use-a-videojs-plugin-when-i-also-use-requirejs/34169488#34169488)

Я работаю над веб-сайтом включающим JS код который я не могу контролировать. Этот код использует RequireJS для загрузки зависимостей.

Заметка: Я новичок в RequireJS. Я понимаю только основы...

На моем веб-сайте мне нужно использовать VideoJS. VideoJS может работать как и с так и без RequireJS, но насколько я понимаю, если RequireJS используется на странице, то я не могу использовать VideoJS без него.

Итак Я загружаю VideoJS с RequireJS вот таким образом:

```
var MyRequire = requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '/_/js',
    paths: {
        videojs: 'http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.3.0/video'
    }
});

MyRequire(["videojs"], function(videojs) {
    videojs('myPlayer', {}, function(){
        console.log('...');
    });
});
```

И это работает.

Но я хочу использовать VideoJS плагин чтобы управлять рекламным роликом перед загрузкой основного видео. (https://github.com/dirkjanm/videojs-preroll)

Я пытался включить скрипт с плагином с RequireJS, скрипт подключается но как только плагин пытается получить доступ к videojs объекту, Я вижу ошибку сообщающую мне что videojs не определен.

Моя догадка заключается в том что когда я загружаю VideoJS как RequireJS модуль, то он находится не в глобальной области видимости, а плагин который я использую ищет VideoJS в глобальной области видимости и в этом причина ошибки.

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ чтобы можно было использовать VideoJS без загрузки его как RequireJS модуль? Или как я могу помочь плагину найти VideoJS объект?

Спасибо за вашу помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно использовать [**shim**](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) из requirejs и включить videojs в **глобальную область видимости**.
Я сделал пример кода для твоего случая. Протестировал и это работает (ты можешь видеть картинки ниже):

Порядок загрузки:

1. "videojs"
2. "add-video-js-in-global-scope"
3. "ads" (at this moment videojs var already in window object)
4. "preroll"

а это как Requirejs анализирует зависимости:

1. requirejs(["preroll", "ads"] - входная точка
2. "preroll" - требует "ads"
3. "ads" - требует "add-video-js-in-global-scope"
4. "add-video-js-in-global-scope" - требует "videojs" и добавляет videojs переменную в объект window.

app.js

```js
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        "videojs": "./libs/video",
        "ads": "./libs/videojs.ads",
        "preroll": "./libs/videojs-preroll"
    },
    shim:{
        "preroll": {
            deps: ['ads']
        },
        "ads": {
            deps: ["add-video-js-in-global-scope"],
        }
    }
});

define("add-video-js-in-global-scope",["videojs"], function(videojs) {
    window.videojs = videojs;
});

requirejs(["preroll", "ads"], function (preroll,ads) {
    // preroll and ads will be undefined because it's not amd.
    videojs('idOne', {}, function () {
        var player = this;
        player.ads(); // initialize the ad framework
        // your custom ad integration code
    });
});
```

index.html

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script data-main="app.js" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.js"></script>
    <div id="idOne"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[результат:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bP0Z5.png)

[файлы:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65Ds1.png)